# AngularJS updating mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angularjs, mongoose

I'm having some trouble updating my mongoDB from a Node server. Sorry, but I'm having some trouble tagging the code. Might come out as regular text. 
The error i get is on the node server and states as follows:

Cast to string failed for value "undefined" at path "text"

Here's my code:

web-server:

```
app.post('/updateArticle/', function(req, res){
console.log("Updating article");
articleModel.update(
    {id: req.id},
    {$set: {title: req.title, text: req.text}});
```

"services:

```
wikiServices.factory('articleService', function($http, $routeParams){
return{
    getArticles: function(callback){
        $http.get('articles/' + $routeParams.article).success(callback);
    },
    updateArticle: function(article, callback){
        $http.post('updateArticle/', article);
    }
};
```

controllers:

```
wikiControllers.controller('articleController', ['$scope', 'articleService',         '$routeParams', '$sanitize',
function($scope, articleService, $routeParams, $sanitize){
articleService.getArticles(function(result){
  $scope.article = result[0];
  console.log($sanitize(result[0].text));
  $scope.articleHTML = $sanitize(result[0].text);
});
$scope.update = function(article, callback){
  articleService.updateArticle(article);
  console.log("test");
};
```

articleEdit:

```
<div text-angular="text-angular" ng-model="article.text"></div>
<div ng-bind-html="article.text"></div>
<a href="#/articles/{{article.id}}">Tilbake</a>
<button ng-click="update()">Lagre forandringer</button>
```

Comment: You have missed some important details. Are you receiving data on the server, or updated data is not being send from client? You need to narrow down whether the error is on server or client or a communication issue.

Comment: The error message I get is: Cast to string failed for value 'undefined' at path 'text', as a server error.

Comment: Replace your console.log above with console.log("Updating article", req) to see if your request actually contains the post fields you think

Comment: Tried: console.log("Updating article", req.article); Got 'undefined'. If I just typed console.log("Updating article", req); I got a really long text which the server log couldn't handle.

Comment: Nvm, guys. Found the answer... thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to send the object in the HTML-function. update("article.text");